# Paging Selected Index Causes DataGrid Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagridview

I am making a web page with asp.net, the problem has to be with a asp:datagrid and its page index changing event. The records are displaying and paging correctly but after making a filter and reduce its grid content and trigger the page index again, the grid refreshes and came back all the other records.

This is my PageLoad()

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtDate1.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter Start Date  DD//MM//YY");
            txtDate2.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter End Date   DD//MM//YY");
            this.bindgrid();
        }
        else
            this.bindgridfilter(txtDate1.Text, txtDate2.Text);
```

My bindGridsmethods()

```
   private void bindgrid()
    {
        ds = Classes.DBMethods.ShowRecords();
        grdRecords.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        grdRecords.DataBind();
    }

    private void bindgridfilter(string date1, string date2)
    {
        dsf = Classes.DBMethods.SearchBetweenDates(date1,date2);
        grdRecords.DataSource = dsf.Tables[0];
        grdRecords.DataBind();
    }
```

My PageIndexChanging Event

```
protected void grdRecords_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdRecords.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdRecords.DataBind();
    }
```

And my FilterButton Click()

```
 protected void Filter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdRecords.DataSource = null;
        bindgridfilter(txtDate1.Text, txtDate2.Text);
    }
```

Now it does the opposite it disappear the grid after making a change of page without a filter, and if it applies a filter now the pagination works correctly

Answer (score 0):

In most web pages, just setting up a drop down list, a grid view, or whatever?

You ONLY want to bind and load the drop down list, or gridview ONE time.

If you re-beind, and re-load the control AGAIN with data, then you will lose your settings.

So, 99% of the time, you want to do such loading ONLY one time,and ONLY on the first page load. Hence, your page load event needs to be this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {      
        txtDate1.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter Start Date  DD//MM//YY");
        txtDate2.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter End Date   DD//MM//YY");
        bindgrid();
    }
}
```

So, now when a button is clicked, or say gv selected index changes, or whatever? Then the information can be used.

If you rebind on each post back, then a gv, or even a simple drop down list will lose its values - hence ONLY load and bind your controls on first "real" page load as per above.

Page load fires EACH time and for each post back. So, any button click or whatever? The page load event will run again. Hence,  your general setup code, startup code, and code to load up things like a drop down list, or gridview?

You need to have a if (!IsPostBack) code stub. The last 200 web pages I have created - everyone has such a code stub, and you really for all purposes can't build a working web page without this "setup" or "first load" code stub. If you re-load or re-setup your controls each time, then anything the user enters or does with such controls will be lost.

Of course YOUR buttons etc. and code can and will re-load the grid, but since the page load fires every time with all and any button click (any post-back), then that re-load code will also re-fire, and  you don't want that to occur.

Comment: Thanks for the explication, unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem, aftter set the **(!IsPostBack)** and change to another page, my grid view doesn't show

Comment: I made few changes to the code but now does the opposite, **changes on original post**

Comment: You don't want that else in the page load. The page load event should not re-bind the GV each time - only on first page load. Index pager changing code again can and will re-bind grid. Remember, page load triggers on all post-backs - including the paging changed event. So, you wind up re-binding the GV two times - that will mess things up. On page load !isPostBack is when you bind the GV. your pager can also re-bind the GV. And if you have code to change the 2 dates? Then again that is a separate event, but if you re-binding  in page load each time, it will mess up each time!

Comment: Your pager event needs to call bindgridfilter. The data pager needs that same criteria. if you just call your databind code without the filter, then the pager will not respect the filter you have.

Comment: Thanks for the advices ! I think I understand your points now more, The changes are already edited, Is this the way you think is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct? PageLoad()

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtDate1.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter Start Date  DD//MM//YY");
            txtDate2.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Enter End Date   DD//MM//YY");
            this.bindgrid();
        }
       
    }
```

PageIndex Event

```
protected void grdRecords_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdRecords.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        if (txtDate1.Text == "" & txtDate2.Text == "")
        {
            bindgrid();
        }
        else
            this.bindgridfilter(txtDate1.Text, txtDate2.Text);
        
    }
```